# GWT classes: an annotation to prevent serialization of a field?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

In GWT 1.7 I have a class used to construct object on the server side which are then used on the client (browser) side.

On the client side I want to cache a service (in this case NumberFormat). This will be initialized lazily in a client-only method, and stored as a field object.

The problem is the Java (1.6) build tools interpret this field as needing to be serialized on the server side (even though it's never accessed on the server).

I could wrap the object in some hander client side but I'd rather specify an annotation to indicate the field will never need serializing for RPC transmission.

```
public class myCrossDomainObject {

  private int someSerializedField;
  private string anotherSerializedField;

  @SomeAnnotationIKnowNotWhat(..)
  private NumberFormat numberFormatterDontSerializeMe;

  // rest of class ......

}
```

Comment: Have you tried marking it transient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
private transient NumberFormat numberFormatterDontSerializeMe;
```

Answer (score 0):

[@GwtTransient](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/GwtTransient.html)

> This annotation means the same thing as the transient keyword, but it
>   is ignored by all serialization systems other than GWT's. Usually the
>   transient keyword should be used in preference to this annotation.
>   However, for types used with multiple serialization systems, it can be
>   useful.
>   Note that GWT will actually accept any annotation named
>   GwtTransient for this purpose. This is done to allow libraries to
>   support GWT serialization without creating a direct dependency on the
>   GWT distribution.

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/GwtTransient.html